# Can we recognizer gestures when iOS in lock screen mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I can detect Lock screen mode in my App like that:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    switch (state) {
        case UIApplicationStateInactive:
            NSLog(@"LockScreen");
            [self.viewController addGestureRecognizersToView:self.viewController.view];
            break;

        case UIApplicationStateBackground:
            NSLog(@"Background");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I want to continue recognizing gestures(tap,longPress...) but don't need to slide to unlock. Is it possible? Which option to control it?

Comment: If this an app for the App Store, then no you can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. If the device is locked. App can almost do nothing for the event handling(except for the remote control event). Because the device will not handle these events. And this is indeed the correct case. If the device still handling the events it will cost a lot of battery energy.

Comment: @Sang you won't be able to get anyone to just tell you how to do that. Remote controlling another device is a complex process.

Comment: @Sang Maybe you misunderstand the remote control event. "A remote-control event originates as commands from the system transport controls or an external accessory conforming to an Apple-provided specification, such as a headset. They are intended to allow users to control multimedia content using those controls and external accessories."

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Your application does not receive gesture input while it is not visible (for instance, when the lock screen is up).